# Which is more appropriate , "was" or "were" and why?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, subjunctives

> If I were you and was ...

Or,

> If I were you and were...

Google results show that the former is correct but hypothetical statements use "were". I'm confused between the two sentences.

Comment: Why do you use was/were after "and"? What are you trying to say?

Comment: The phrase is normally just *if I were you*. I don't know why *and (was/were)* is coming afterwards. Neither version is particularly appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean a sentence like, "If I were you and [was/were] planning this party..."?

"Were" is the technically correct option in this case, for the reason you described. There are two hypotheticals: *if I were* in your place, and *if I were* planning the party. The same rules apply to both.

That said, this particular rule often gets ignored in casual speech, and you might hear it both ways.